# Hive Metastore asking for Derby DB in default

Tags: hadoop, hive

Just for a query. Am having a hadoop 1 cluster.
In hive am using Oracle/MySQL as a MetaStore DB, but when the MR job is being trigger I could see the Every Time Hive executing a Query Operation every time it seeking Derby DB instead of MySQL/Oracle DB.

For Setting default DB in hive-site.xml and hive-default.xml have passed the

```
<property>
  <name>hive.stats.dbclass</name>
  <value>jdbc:oracle</value>
  <description>The default database that stores temporary hive statistics.</description>
</property>
```

with other parameters like **hive.stats.dbconnectionstring**  or **javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL**
along with so is there any other changes required,
As of now what have been applied is have removed the DERBY jar from the Lib location of the cluster, so while trying to access the Derby DB its getting failed and afterword it's checking Oracle/MySQL Connector to access the same.

Any workaround can be done, as every time Hive is searching for DERBY DB, which causing bit a load for processing Job.

Comment: The `Configuration` constructors search for "xxxxx-site.xml" config files in **directories present in the CLASSPATH** and if they don't find any, they revert silently (!!) to hard-coded "default" values -- e.g. DERBY. So make sure that your CLASSPATH starts with sthg like `/etc/hadoop/conf/:/etc/hive/conf/:......`

Comment: hi Samson, the configuration have been done already as u have mention... but still its not working, I have pass the configuration of hive at the end of the line in the hadoop-env.sh CLASSPATH staring with 1st-Hadoop, 2nd Hbase.. , any other points could u guide